# fancybox is not requesting the proper page using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".modalbox").fancybox({

  type: 'ajax',
  ajax : {
        type    : "GET",
        URL: 'requestajax.php',
        data    : {cid:'3'},
        error: function(){
    alert('failure');
  }
    }
});
```

so this is my code, when I use firebug I see that the data is being passed (under parameters)
but the url requested is the same file index.php instead it should say requestajax.php?cid=3
any ideas ? I think I am doing something wrong.
the modal box is loaded with the index.php content instead of requestajax.php. thats issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your URL as `href` parameter:

```
$(".modalbox").fancybox({
    href : 'requestajax.php',
    type : 'ajax',
    ajax : {
        type  : "GET",
        data  : {cid:'3'},
        error: function(){
            alert('failure');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the

```
URL: 'requestajax.php',
```

has to be in lowercase like this:

```
url: 'requestajax.php',
```

Anyway you have to be careful with the options in JavaScript as onStart is different from onstart.

If this is not the case then try to add an absolute url to your fancybox, for example:

```
url: '/requestajax.php',
```

Comment: tried lower case first and then upper case none worked. I had to use: href before the ajax call :) thanks Johnny